# Custom directive with dynamic field name in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am creating reusable custom directive in angularjs where I am looking to pass fieldName for ng-repeate items as attribute. All my scope is isolated

My part of directive codes as below

```
<div class="list">
   <label ng-repeat="item in items" class="item item-text-wrap">
       {{item.City}}
   </label>
</div>
```

In above code I am passing fieldName hard code but I want to pass City (i.e. field name) by attribute
of my custom directive

```
<custom-select items="deptStations" drop-down-field="City"></custom-select>
```

in above items are passed by http service from controller

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.xxxx.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('XXX')/items?$select=Id,City_Code,City&$filter=Active eq 1&$orderby=City asc", {
    headers: {
      Accept : "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
  }).then(function(resp) {
    $scope.deptStations = resp.data.d.results;
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

So idea over here is that I want to pass drop-down-field and I want to pass in my directive. Is it possible, if yes then how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think below code will solve your problem

```js
angular.module("module").directive("customSelect", function(){
  return{
    scope : {
      dropDownField : '@',
      items : '='
    };
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="list">
   <label ng-repeat="item in items" class="item item-text-wrap">
       {{item[dropDownField]}}
   </label>
</div>
```